# Sublime Text 3 marks things without a reason

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

To me it is unclear why Sublime Text 3 marks things without having selected some other text. It bothers me because I cannot focus clearly because of this.

Does somebody know how to 'reset' Sublime Text 3 to let it function normally as before?

[image: Sublime Text 3 Marking]

Comment: Have you got any plugins installed?

Comment: I have installed Anaconda.

Comment: If you disable that does the expected functionality return?

Comment: The disable and enable action worked the first time. Unfortunately, it appeared again and is not solvable with the disable and enable action.